# Groovy Dsl's, which book to follow?

Tags: groovy

Which Book is best for learning Groovy DSL's? I came across this book : [Groovy For DSL's](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/184719690X) . Apart from this book are there any other books, blogs,site tutorials for learning DSL's using Groovy from scratch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't find any other book on the subject. I'm waiting for the second edition of [Groovy in Action](http://www.manning.com/koenig2/), but it seems DSL part is light

Not related to Groovy but [Domain-Specific Languages](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321712943) by Martin Fowler is quite a good book for explaing scope of dsl, examples and patterns.